# Block port from the outside except for Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, port, iptables

I installed a jenkins via Docker on my server and assigned to a specific domain (jenkins.mydomain.com), which works perfectly fine. But I can also reach jenkins (and every other service in docker) if I browse my domain with the service's port, for example: mydomain.com:8181 
I'v already tried a few thing to block the port from the outside and make it only accessible via domain, but no luck. 
First I tried to block the port for the eth0 interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 8181 -j DROP
```

But it didn't work because when I tried to reach jenkins from the domain, I'v got an error 503. 
Also tried to block the port for every incoming requests except docker's ip. It didn't work either.
So how can I make the ports unaccessible from the outside but accessible for Docker?

---

iptables -L -n --line-numbers

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3000
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:22
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:8081
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:50000
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:8080

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Post Dockerfile and Jenkins config please :) (and the command you're using to run the container)